# Missing posts in a query

Tags: query, taxonomy

I've got this loop where I need to grab a custom post type, get a taxonom, then for each term in taxonomy I need to output all posts. They are all output in a gallery, where taxonomy term is the title, posts are the items in the gallery (for that I use http://bit.ly/1jCf2Wj). I have something like this:

```
<?php 

        global $post;
        $post_type = 'people';
        $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );
        $tax = $taxonomies[0];
        $terms = get_terms( $tax );

        //make the query
        $people_args = array( 'post_type' => $post_type);  
        $loop = new WP_Query( $people_args ); //look for people posts
        $termsLength = count($terms);// count terms in the taxonomy, returns correct number

        //for each people post
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        //for each term in the taxonomy
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $termsLength-1; $x++) {
          //this is all posts looped by terms length - 1 

          //if the post has got the name (department name) in $tax (departments group)
          if( has_term( $terms[$x]->name, $tax ) ) {

            echo '<div style="display:block;clear:both; margin-left:0px; z-index:9999; ">'. $terms[$x]->name .'</div>';

            // echo '<div style="display:block;clear:both; margin-left:990px; z-index:9999;">'.$wp_query->post_count.'</div>';
            $name = $terms[$x]->name; // dept name
            $title = get_the_title($post->ID); // the post title
            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail_size' ); // the post thumb
            $url = $thumb['0']; // url to thumb
            echo '<li data-pile="'. $name .'">';
            echo '<a href="#">';
            echo '<span class="tp-info"><span>'.$title.'</span><span class="profile-smaller">'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'position', true).'</span></span>';
            echo '<img src="'. $url .'" />';
            echo '</a></li> ';

          }
        }

        endwhile;
        rewind_posts(); wp_reset_query();

        ?>
```

What happens is I get the the results of the query, but not all posts are there. If I publish more posts than x, then one of taxonomy terms (departments) are not showing up. Another taxonomy term shows only one post.

Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out setting explicity posts per page did if for me.

Comment: Did you set posts_per_page to -1?

Comment: Not the right thing to do, but I've set it to 9999999.